# Почему при загрузке не устанавливается 'checked'. localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

Почитал ***Google***. Вроде делаю правильно, но не работает. Ошибок в консоли нет.

Когда `checked` создается строка `link` с путем на файл `css`, когда нет `checked` строка удаляется. Записал в `localStorage (отображается в хранилище данные)`.

Написал условие `If`, но при обновлении страницы `checked` не ставится.

Не знаю уже куда копать без ошибок в консоли.

с `localstorage` работаю впервые

```js
function darkTheme() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('darkTheme'),
    newLink = document.createElement('link'),
    head = document.getElementById('head');

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    newLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    newLink.href = "theme-for-night.css";
    newLink.id = "link";
    head.insertBefore(newLink, head.children[7]); //создать link на 7ой строчке родителя head
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'on'); //on если checked
  } else {
    link.remove(newLink);
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'off'); //off если убран checked
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('darkTheme') == 'on') {
    document.getElementById('darkTheme').checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<head id="head">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Основной файл стилей-->
  <!--Эта строка добавляется если checked и удаляется если не checked. Файл с ночной темой-->
  <link href="theme-for-night.css" rel="stylesheet" id="link">
</head>
```

---

Вдруг, это кому-то поможет из новичков:

```
        <script>
        function darkTheme()
        {
            var inp = document.getElementById('darkTheme');
            //
            if(inp.checked){
                changeTheme();//Фунция добавить тему
                localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'on');
            }else{
                removeTheme();//Функция удалить тему
                localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'off');
            }
        }
        //Включить тему, если darkTheme = 'on'
        function changeTheme()
        {
            var head = document.getElementById('head'),
                createLink = document.createElement('link');
                //
                createLink.rel = "stylesheet";
                createLink.href = "theme-for-night.css";
                createLink.id = "link";
                head.insertBefore(createLink, head.children[7]);
        }
        //Удалить тему, если darkTheme = 'off'
        function removeTheme()
        {
            var rm = document.getElementById('link');
            rm.remove();
        }
        //Функция на загрузку  страницы
        window.onload = function()
        {
            var inp = document.getElementById('darkTheme');

            if(localStorage.getItem('darkTheme') == 'on'){
                changeTheme();
                inp.checked = true;
            }
        }
    </script>

<div>
  <!-- кнопка которая добавляет строчку с id="link" -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="darkTheme" onclick="darkTheme()">
</div>
```

Comment: какой код вызывается во время загрузки страницы?

Comment: Покажи весь код

Comment: @Air вот посмотрите пожалуйста https://jsfiddle.net/9txfn6g0/2/ . Теперь при перезагрузке страницы если в хранилище значение on то ставится чекбокс, но не создается link.

Comment: @Igor  вот посмотрите пожалуйста jsfiddle.net/9txfn6g0/2 . Теперь при перезагрузке страницы если в хранилище значение on то ставится чекбокс, но не создается link. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `var checkbox = document.getElementById('darkTheme')` Первое, что бросилось в глаза, это название переменной `checkbox` я не нашел его в зарезервированных слова **JS**, но именно из-за этого у тебя **script** не видит `input` и второе не верно название функции `dar*l*Theme` а должно быть `dar*k*Theme`

Comment: Далее что-то не то с функцией `window.onload`

Comment: И это строке не  верный коммент `head.insertBefore(newLink, head.children[7]); //создать link на 7ой строчке родителя head`,  а  `вставить link перед  7м дочерним элементом`

Comment: @Air newLink.remove() не удаляет строчку, а link.remove() удаляет. Я не могу использовать имя checkbox для переменной ? Или я неправильно понял что-то?

Comment: `newLink.remove()` Удаляет все прекрасно. И да ты верно понял, нельзя  использовать имя переменной `checkbox`

Comment: Прощу прощения, вот так надо удалять `document.getElementById('link').remove();` просто ошибся  идентификатором

Comment: НО в целом, тебе надо будет переписывать все... Не верное условие... В общем все придется переписывать... Если ни кто не ответит, чуть позже буду за компом, напишу ответ.

Comment: Можете намекнуть на логику, как правильно написать ? (Я не силен в JS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример  тут работать не будет....

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (input.checked) {
    addDarkTheme();
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'on');
    console.log(localStorage.theme);
  } else {
    removeDarkTheme();
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'off');
    console.log(localStorage.theme);
  }
})

function addDarkTheme() {
  document.querySelector('head').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<link rel="stylesheet" id="dark-theme"  href="theme-for-night.css"/>');
}

function removeDarkTheme() {
  document.querySelector('#dark-theme').remove();
}

window.onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.theme == 'on') {
    addDarkTheme();
    input.checked = true;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="input">
```

Comment: Этот код работает верно, но он не показателен в плане ошибки, которую совершил автор, однако от меня плюс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я ему ошибки в комментариях описал, Благодарю

Comment: Однако ошибка была в другом, посмотрите мой ответ =)

Comment: Согласен проглядел, но это не единственная ошибка

Comment: это значит что автор исправлял вопрос

Comment: @Air Спасибо. Прямо сейчас я изучил урок, и сделал абсолютно все сам узнав ошибки. Я не стал использовать Ваш код, а изъял лишь логику и написал с первого раза на одном дыхании без каких либо ошибок.

Comment: Рад был помочь.............

Answer (score 1):

Что касается чекбокса - вы не правильно ищете его на странице, он у вас задан с  `id="checkbox"`, а ищете вы его  `document.getElementById('darkTheme')`

Вот рабочий код, в нем я просто поменял в разметке идентификатор на `"darkTheme"`:

```js
function darkTheme() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('darkTheme')

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'on'); //on если checked
  } else {
 
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', 'off'); //off если убран checked
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('darkTheme') == 'on') {
    document.getElementById('darkTheme').checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="darkTheme" onclick="darkTheme()">
</div>
```

Comment: Подождите, чем он отличается от моего и почему он работает? Но взглянув на Ваш код, у меня родилась идея, как написать тоже самое, но рабочее не использовав готовый код снизу, который дал @Air

Comment: @ОлегБыков я написал в ответе, <input type="checkbox" id="darkTheme" onclick="darkTheme()">, обратите внимание на  id="darkTheme", у вас там было id="checkbox"

Comment: Ах, приношу извинения) Просто я ночью писал всё, и указала id="checkbox" по случайности. В редакторе с кодом стоит id="darkTheme".

Comment: @ОлегБыков Нет проблем,  значит были еще какие-то ошибки, которые вы уже поправили

Comment: Держи плюс.......

Comment: @Air премного благодарен :)